# Python Matrix check for diagonals and horizontals correctly to win a game

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I'm building a game like Connect4 the user can connect any number. I am having a problem checking the horizontal and diagonals lines:

```
def WinningSequenceCheck(board,piece,row_count):
    #Horizontal Check
    piecePlayer1=0
    piecePlayer2=0
    win_sequence=board[0]["TamanhoSequência"]
    width=board[0]["CumpGrelha"]
    height=row_count

    for c in range(height+1):
        for r in range(width):
            if board[0]["Tabuleiro"][c][r]==1:
                piecePlayer1+=1
                if piecePlayer1==win_sequence:
                    return True                    
            if board[0]["Tabuleiro"][c][r]==2:
                pecasPlayer2+=1
                if pecasPlayer2==win_sequence:
                    return True

#For diagonals i did this:
    diag1=0
    diag2=0
    a=0
    b=height
    d=0
    for c in range(width):
        for l in range(height+1):
            if board[0]["Tabuleiro"][b-l][l+a]==1:
                diag1+=1
                if diag1==win_sequence:
                    return True                    
            if board[0]["Tabuleiro"][b-l][l+a]==2:
                diag2+=1
                if diag2==win_sequence:
                    return True
            if (b-l<height):
                b=height
                if l<=l-1:
                    a=a
                elif(a+l<width-1):
                    a+=1 
                elif(a+l<=width-1):
                    return        
                else:
                    break
```

The problem with diagonals is that it goes from left to right but it's not checking properly if there is a line of a winning sequence of 1s or 2s
If it finds it should return true because im incrementing each time he finds 1 or 2

Im i doing the horizontal check properly?
Is there a better way to check in diagonals ?

The expected result from the horizontal is that if it finds the number 1 it adds to the variable piecePlayer1 (for the player 1)
If the piecePlayer1 is equal to Victory sequence ( example victory sequence is 5) the game returns true because in one of the lines he found 5 one's .

```
Winning Sequence=5
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ---> Win
```

The same is for the diagonal check:

```
Winning Sequence =4
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] Diagonal WIN
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: You may want to give a few concrete examples - such as inputs and expected outputs, so that people can understand your question clearly.

Comment: I used some examples . Can you see if its more clear?

Comment: How do you use the function? what are board,piece,row_count? Please notice that if it is not well explained we cannot understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

@Stunna,  here is simple sample code to check the `diagonal` values, you can try it and modify to suit your main module:

```
def winner(board, length):
    """Returns the 'mark' of the winning player"""
    W = range(len(board))     # width
    H = range(len(board[0]))  # height
    directions = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, -1)]
    
    for dx, dy in directions:
        edges = []  
        
        if dx > 0:
            edges += [(0, y) for y in H]
            
        if dy > 0:   # scanning down
            edges += [(x, 0) for x in W]
            
        if dy < 0:   # scanning up
            edges += [(x, H[-1]) for x in W]
            
        for ex, ey in edges: 
            row = 0; mark = None
            x, y = ex, ey
            
            while x in W and y in H:
                if board[x][y] == mark:
                    row += 1
                else:
                    mark = board[x][y]
                    row = 1
                if mark is not None and row >= length:
                    return mark
                x, y = x + dx, y + dy
    return None

print(winner([
    ['X', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['O', 'X', 'O', 'X'],
    ['O', 'O', 'X', 'O'],
    ['O', 'X', 'X', 'X'] ], 4))  # X
```

Comment: Mark is the goal right? so i want that if he finds a 1 in each diagonal line it increments and
if the total of 1's is equal to the winning sequence it returns

Comment: You are correct. Try to play with it and understand the flowing... then you could modify it... Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok ill check , im getting an error on 'int' object is not iterable on edges += [(x, 0) for x in W]

Comment: When the code is running as it's - it's fine. IF you change anything, or missing some - it will have `different` results.  So what's your changes?   If you just run it - it is working? Correct?

Comment: yeah i executed and it worked normally but it looks like it's going on horizontal .. maybe because im awfull at python i don't understand.. but i just need that if he finds 1 in a diagonal he increments if he finds a 2 he increments if the the time he is running the sum of the pieces 1 is equal to the winning sequence(for example 5 ) returns true games closes and winner is player 1 otherwise is player 2

Comment: OK. to check diagonal is easy if you know it's depending on `(r-c) ` releations - eg. (0.0) -> (1,1) -> (2,2), (3, 3) etc. will let you check  Here, r is row, c is col - coordinates.